Error continues to occur saying that the list is empty in JSP?
I want to put data values ​​from db into Employee class and then display all values ​​in JSP file. However, an error continues to occur saying that the list is empty.


Employee.java
package employee;


import java.util.Date;

public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Date hireDate;

    public Employee() {
    }

   
    public Employee(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, Date hireDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.hireDate = hireDate;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Date getHireDate() {
        return hireDate;
    }

    public void setHireDate(Date hireDate) {
        this.hireDate = hireDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", hireDate=" + hireDate +
                '}';
    }
}


EmployeeServlet.java
package employee;

import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/employees", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class EmployeeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

        String url = "jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/test03";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "1234";

        try {
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException("JDBC Driver not found.");
        }


        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, first_name, last_name, email, hire_date FROM employees")) {

            while (rs.next()) {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                employee.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
                employee.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
                employee.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                employee.setHireDate(rs.getDate("hire_date"));
                employees.add(employee);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        request.setAttribute("employees", employees);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/employees.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}



employees.jsp
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="employee.Employee" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>


<%
    List<Employee> employees = (List<Employee>) request.getAttribute("employees");
    if (employees == null || employees.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Employee list is empty or null.");
    }
%>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Hire Date</th>
    </tr>
    <%
        if (employees != null) {
            for (Employee employee : employees) {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= employee.getId() %></td>
        <td><%= employee.getFirstName() %></td>
        <td><%= employee.getLastName() %></td>
        <td><%= employee.getEmail() %></td>
        <td><%= employee.getHireDate() %></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    } else {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">No data found.</td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
</table>




The data clearly exists and seems to have been connected correctly, but when I run it, it is empty.



The data values come from servlet and it is not set in the JSP directly.

You didn't set the request attribute in the servlet because you use the request url http://localhost:8080/ex01_war/employees.jsp
The code request.getAttribute("employees") returns null.
When JSP is forwarded from servlet to JSP then it keeps its attributes.
But you should use http://localhost:8080/ex01_war/employees.
If you manually enter this url in the browser then Http GET request is performed which is handled by the doGet() method. Then you fill employees list and set request attribute request.setAttribute("employees", employees); before forwarding to JSP.
When JSP is rendered then it will get the request attribute previously set in the servlet. So, it won't be null and the list will be iterated in for loop.
